# Django/Docker/pyaudio: pip install failed beaucause of #include "portaudio.h"

Tags: python, django, docker, pyaudio

I am using Django on Docker with python:3.8.3-alpine image and want to use pyaudio librairy but pip install failed because of portaudio dependency

> rc/pyaudio/device_api.c:9:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file
> or directory
> 9 | #include "portaudio.h"
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~

I've tried many thing like trying to install portaudio before but nothing works

maybe comes from my python image but trying python:3.8.3 image is too long to build

How to use pyaudio in DJango/Docker project?

Answer (score 1):

The alpine docker container is minimal; you can first narrow down the problem by using a [standard python docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/python) container and see if the pyaudio pip install works.  If that's the case it's likely that you'll need to install more into your alpine container in your `Dockerfile`, starting with the python3 dev tools, for example:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3-dev
```